# Coderush not analyzing C++ solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, coderush

Should CodeRush analyze the current solution in Visual Studio by default? I cannot get it to show me anything about my solution/project.

I just downloaded the Code Rush trail version and I'm trying to have it do some analysis of my solution in VS2010. I've opened the Duplicate Code and Code Issues screens but I cannot get them to display anything. When I refresh the Duplicate Code screen it returns in 0.005 seconds with 0 clusters.

It seems like CodeRush is not looking at my solution/project, but I don't know how to point it to my solution/project.

I've tried looking through the online documentation of getting started, but everything I've read looks like it should just work out of the box.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q446606

Comment: Thank you @jessehouwing. That link did help me enable a lot of features that were not turned on by default. I still can't seem to run the Duplicate Code and Code Issues analysis, but I'm thinking that might be disabled for C++.

Comment: I just read that c++ will be deprecated https://www.devexpress.com/Products/CodeRush/cpp11.xml

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not supported using C++, only C# and VB are supported.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted DevExpress, and they confirmed that the "Duplicate Code" and "Code Issues" functionality is not supported for the C++ language. Thanks again to @jessehouwing for helping me enable the limited features that do work with C++.